# Add x number of working days to a date in a custom column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, powerquery, m

I'm trying to add a custom column in Power Query that adds 3 **business days** if a condition is met, else add 2 business days.

I can have it conditionally add days without issue, but am having trouble adding workdays instead. I know this is easily done in excel using `=IF X = 1,WORKDAY([REFERENCE],3),WORKDAY([REFERENCE],2)` but how can I do the same thing as a custom column in the query editor?

Below is what I have, which does days including weekends:

`=if [REF]="1" then Date.AddDays([ETA],3) else Date.AddDays([ETA],2)`

Comment: Well, after all, it is only 4 short years since. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a custom function that solves this problem, unless you need to take holidays into account too. It is a bit universal,  it works with 2 or 200 or 2000 added days. Equals `=WORKDAY(date;days)` function in Excel.

UPDATE: [Bibake Uppal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13345617/bibake-uppal) suggested there should be subtraction supported.  Added subtraction for negative `days`.

Here it is:

```
(startDate, days) =>
    let
        Sign = if days < 0 then -1 else 1, //add a multiplier to enable negative 'days' to be subtracted rather than added
        Step1 = List.Dates(Date.AddDays(startDate, Sign), Sign*days + Number.RoundUp(Sign*days/7*3+4,0), #duration(Sign,0,0,0)), //provision list of added days with 3 more days per each added week, starting from startDate + 1 day; This is a bit over-provisioning, but ensures the list is long enough.
        Step2 = List.Select(Step1, (item) => Date.DayOfWeek(item, Day.Monday) < 5), // select only workdays
        Step3 = List.FirstN(Step2, Sign*days), //select required number of workdays
        Output = if days = 0 then startDate else List.Last(Step3)
    in
        Output
```

You can save it as a query, name it, say, `AddWorkdays`, and use as this:

```
YourStepName = Table.AddColumn(yourTable, "CustomColumnName", 
                    each AddWorkdays([ETA], if [REF]="1" then 3 else 2) 
                   //note that [REF]="1" filters a text value, not number!
```

Otherwise you can insert this function in your code as

```
fnAddWorkdays = (startDate, days) =>
let
    Sign = if days < 0 then -1 else 1, //add a multiplier to enable negative 'days' to be subtracted rather than added
    Step1 = List.Dates(Date.AddDays(startDate, Sign), Sign*days +  Number.RoundUp(Sign*days/7*3+4,0), #duration(Sign,0,0,0)), //provision list of added days with 3 more days per each added week, starting from startDate + 1 day; This is a bit over-provisioning, but ensures the list is long enough.
    Step2 = List.Select(Step1, (item) => Date.DayOfWeek(item, Day.Monday) < 5), // select only workdays
    Step3 = List.FirstN(Step2, Sign*days), //select required number of workdays
    Output = if days = 0 then startDate else List.Last(Step3)
in
    Output
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to break it down into 2 components:

1. Based on your initial condition, add 2 or 3 days
2. If this ends on a Saturday or Sunday, add 2 additional days to skip over the weekend

You have already implemented Step 1.

You now just need to implement Step 2, which is to add the 2 additional days if required. You can use DayOfWeek function to determine where you started, to determine if you'll need the extra 2 days:

If you're adding 3 business days, then you'll need to add 2 additional days if the initial day is Wed, Thu or Fri:

```
if Date.DayOfWeek([ETA], Day.Wednesday) <= 2 then {Add 2 more days}
```

If you're adding 2 business days, then you'll need to add 2 additional days if the initial day is Thu or Fri:

```
if Date.DayOfWeek([ETA], Day.Thursday) <= 1 then {Add 2 more days}
```

You can incorporate these into your initial statement.

Comment: Michael, your code provides wrong solution. 1st, wednesday + 2 business days = friday. 2nd, `Date.DayOfWeek([ETA], Day.Wednesday) <= 3` means *wendesday - saturday*. 3rd, there are cases when 2 or 3 days should be added, this needs different handling.

Comment: I've clarified my answer. I was simply providing a solution to add 2 additional days if required to handle the weekend. I also assumed the OP could handle modifying the code for the additional case. They just need to be added the line of code the OP already developed.

Comment: that wasn't the only issue. `Date.DayOfWeek(#date(2017,2,15), Day.Wednesday) equals 0`. `Date.DayOfWeek(#date(2017,2,18), Day.Wednesday) equals 3`. Both hit your condition `if Date.DayOfWeek([ETA], Day.Wednesday) <= 3`.

Answer (score 0):

Slight improvement on Eugene's response to allow for the subtraction of workdays as well.

```
= (startDate, days) =>
let
    Step1 = if days >= 0 then List.Dates(Date.AddDays(startDate, 1), days + Number.RoundUp(days/7*3+4,0), #duration(1,0,0,0)) 
            else List.Dates(Date.AddDays(startDate, -1), -days + Number.RoundUp(-days/7*3+4,0), #duration(-1,0,0,0)), //provision list of added days with 3 more days per each added week, starting from startDate + 1 day
    Step2 = List.Select(Step1, (item) => Date.DayOfWeek(item, Day.Monday) < 5), // select only workdays
    Step3 = List.FirstN(Step2, Number.Abs(days)), //select required number of workdays
    Output = List.Last(Step3)
in
    Output
```

Simply put in a negative value for `days`.

Comment: Thanks! Edited original post to provide a version.